# How can I register an angularjs factory after the app has "started" / been loaded?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I've got the guts of a routing architecture in Angular that will dynamically download and inject Angular Controllers and Services ... the Controller part works fine, and I'm trying to download dependant services via $route's .resolve property.

Now, say if I have a factory declared in scope while the page starts up, it registers fine and Controllers that use it resolve fine, e.g:

```
myModule.factory('MyInjectedDep', function() {
    return {};
});

....

MyController = function(MyInjectedDep)
```

But if I try and register that dependency at "run time" (for want of a better phrase), I get a Circular Dependency error. e.g:

```
$route.routes[routeItem.route] = {
   resolve: {
      MyInjectedDep: ['$injector', function($injector) {
          // In real code I download/eval this via $http but same behavior occurs
          myModule.factory('MyInjectedDep', function() {
              return {};
          });
      }]
   }
}
```

So when my Controller is then initiated:

```
MyController = function(MyInjectedDep)
```

I get a circular dependency error, but no dependency trace in the error message?

```
Error: Circular dependency:
```

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is latching onto $provide at configuration time.  If you grab $provide at configuration time and maintain a reference to it, you can use it to register your factory like:

```
$provide.factory.apply(null, ['MyInjectedDep', [function() {
   return {};
]}]);
```

I have a provider/service designed to do this, adapted from some other samples on github: https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-couchPotato .

It's primarily designed to load from AMD, but you could probably use it's registerXXX functions with $http, or at least copy the relevant portions of its code.  Don't let the size of the repository fool you -- the actual provider/service is about one page of code https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-couchPotato/blob/master/src/couchPotato.js .

Comment: Looks promising ... I'll try your answer and report back. Thanks

Comment: @stu.salsbury the lazy loading example that u have specified in github. will it work in IE8 ?

Comment: @Prashanth -- I haven't tested with any form of IE, but as far as I know it will work.  If you try it and it doesn't, I'd really appreciate feedback through a Github issue in the repository!